# Why do I get an error in angular if the return of the api is correct?

Tags: angularjs, json, wordpress

I make a API call to Wordpress with Angular:

```
angular.module('assetApp.services',[])
    .factory('Asset', function($resource, $cacheFactory) {
        var assetsCache = $cacheFactory('Assets');
        var res = $resource('/wp-json/wp/v2/assets?&tags=:tags&posts_per_page=40&page=:page', {
            'get': { method:'GET', cache: assetsCache, isArray:true },
            'query': { method:'GET', params:{}, cache: assetsCache, isArray:true }
        });
        return res;
    }).factory('Category', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/wp-json/wp/v2/asset_category/', {
            'get': { method:'GET' },
        });
    });
```

an become in the console the follow error:

```
angular.min.js?ver=1539242296:2920 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

If i test the API with a Rest API tool it returns a valid JSON.

Comment: That error Is almost certainly because your requests hits a html-page instead of json. Have you tried looking at the request-preview in your browser dev-tools?

Comment: You can try something like this:
$resource('/wp-json/wp/v2/asset_category/', {
        'get': { method:'GET', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'} }
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding responseType: 'text'

```
 $resource('/wp-json/wp/v2/asset_category/', { 'get': { method:'GET',  responseType: 
'text' } })
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a error while parsing JSON, your JSON is not correct if you wants to you can check your JSON format at
[JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)
 else you can check your json format by installing json viewer chrome extension